# How do I wrap this shell command in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to wrap the following linux command into the Perl system function?

```
date --set="$(ssh richard@192.168.0.4 'date -u')"
```

I have tried the following but cannot find a combination that works:

```
use strict;
system("date --set="$(ssh richard@192.168.0.4 'date -u')"");
system, "date", "--set="$(ssh richard@192.168.0.4 'date -u')"";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Wouldn't it be easier to use ntp?

Comment: You try to reinvent _the wheel_, there is [rdate](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rdate) for such case. But __ntp__ is even better option, or are you just exercise in Perl programming?

Comment: Other option could be [ntpdate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpdate), check _tools_ at your disposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use backticks to run a command through your shell. The backtick is an expression that evaluates to the standard output of the command you execute.

```
use strict;
my $remote_date = `ssh richard\@192.168.0.4 'date -u'`;
chomp $remote_date;
system("date --set='$remote_date'");
```

The variable `$remote_date` will contain whatever `ssh` would print on the screen, including, possibly, login messages. The newline programs typically print at the end of every line will also be included, so I threw in a `chomp`.

This assumes the command ran successfully. You can check the exit status of a program with the `$?` variable, but I am not sure, in your case, if this would give you the status of `ssh` or the remote `date` command you attempted to execute.

Comment: Yes it worked but I had to add an escape (richard\@192.168.0.4). Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: `ssh` can fail on its own, of course (host not found, invalid SSH key, etc) but otherwise, it simply relays back the exit status of the remote shell; so, in this case, the exit status of the remote `date` command (the exit status of a sequence of shell commands is the exit status of the last one of them).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you didn't escape the `"`, `$` and `@` within.

```perl
system( "date --set=\"\$( ssh richard\@192.168.0.4 'date -u' )\"" );
```

In this case, it's cleaner to use single-quotes on the outside, and double-quotes on the inside.

```perl
system( 'date --set="$( ssh richard@192.168.0.4 "date -u" )"' );
```

Answer (score 2):

#### wrap commands in `Perl`, with or without variables/special characters:

```
use strict; use warnings;
my $remote_date = system<<'EOF';
ssh richard@192.168.0.4 'date -u'
EOF
chomp $remote_date;
system<<EOF;
date --set='$remote_date'
EOF
```

##### Check [`perldoc perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Especially the part about `'QuoteHereDocument'`